# Use audio files or text to speech for iOS application

Tags: ios, audio, text-to-speech, voice

I am creating an iOS game in which I have to inform user about events in the game with voice, that you have moved one piece, 2 pieces or well done you have performed well.
The problem is that voices are in large amount and if I replace audio files for each voice the app size will grow very large.
Second option I have discovered is to use text-to-speech library. I have tried  ["**OpenEars**"](http://www.politepix.com/openears/) but the issue is I want voice like cartoon character or bird like which is not available in any of open source text-to-speech libraries as far as I have searched.
Can anybody suggest me what is the better way to handle it or any text-to-speech framework with different voice capabilities as mentioned in above paragraph.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding text to speech functionality to iOS app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194170/adding-text-to-speech-functionality-to-ios-app)

Comment: I have gone through from that answer already and didn't find it useful in my case so asked here.

Answer (score 1):

VoiceForge offers different TTS voices.

http://www.voiceforge.com