# How to build a speech-to-text app using Swift in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, text, speech-to-text, speech

I'm trying to write an iOS app (Coding in Swift) that converts speech into text and display that text in a TextView. I'm using the OpenEars library. But, so far I haven't found any materials for Swift that show how to convert speech into text.

How to convert speech into text and display it in a TextView?

Comment: hello...in case you didnt find any solution yet...check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194170/adding-text-to-speech-functionality-to-ios-app?rq=1

Comment: this would be a step to step tutorial with some external framework :http://www.raywenderlich.com/60870/building-ios-app-like-siri

Comment: Hi @user2201650,if you have done this could you please tell me how.i have to implement the same in my app.Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://developer.nuance.com/public/Help/DragonMobileSDKReference_iOS/Speech-recognition.html They have an API for that.

Comment: if you're learning swift, i'd suggest going with the latest version 3, apple started to offer speech recognition API with iOS10, so go for it